# How to create a dropdown list in a form of registration for customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, frontend, forms

I want to create a new attribute named status as a dropdown list that contain 6  static values.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps:

**Step:1** Create `registration.php` at location `app/code/Stack/Customer` and below code:

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Stack_Customer',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step:2** Create `module.xml` at locatin app/code/Stack/Customer/etc/ and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Stack_Customer" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

**Step:3** Create `UpgradeData.php` at location `app/code/Stack/Customer/Setup/` and add below code

```
<?php
namespace Stack\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
    * put your comment there...
    * 
    * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
    * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
    */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $attributeCode = "customer_status";
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, [
            'type'              => 'varchar',
            'label'             => 'Customer Status',
            'input'             => 'select',
            'source'            => 'Stack\Customer\Model\Attribute\Source\CustomerStatus',
            'required'          => false,
            'visible'           => true,
            'user_defined'      => true,
            'sort_order'        => 220,
            'position'          => 220,
            'system'            => false,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode)
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' =>  ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    } 
}
```

**Step:4** Create file `CustomerStatus.php` at location `app/code/Stack/Customer/Model/Attribute/Source` and add below code:

```
<?php
namespace Stack\Customer\Model\Attribute\Source;

/**
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class CustomerStatus extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table
{

    const STATUS_BLANK    = '';
    const STATUS_ACTIVE   = 'A';
    const STATUS_ONHOLD   = 'I';
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 'P';

    const STATUS_BLANK_TEXT     = '';
    const STATUS_ACTIVE_TEXT    = 'Active';
    const STATUS_ONHOLD_TEXT    = 'On Hold';
    const STATUS_INACTIVE_TEXT  = 'Inactive';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Convert\DataObject
     */
    protected $_converter;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory $attrOptionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Convert\DataObject $converter
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory $attrOptionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Convert\DataObject $converter
    ) {
        $this->_converter = $converter;
        parent::__construct($attrOptionCollectionFactory, $attrOptionFactory);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $this->_options[] = ['value' => self::STATUS_BLANK, 'label' => self::STATUS_BLANK_TEXT]; 
        $this->_options[] = ['value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE, 'label' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE_TEXT]; 
        $this->_options[] = ['value' => self::STATUS_ONHOLD, 'label' => self::STATUS_ONHOLD_TEXT]; 
        $this->_options[] = ['value' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE, 'label' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE_TEXT]; 

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

**Step :5** Now override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` file in your theme and after add below code in this file

```
<div class="field customer_status">
    <label for="customer_status" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer Status')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="customer_status" name="customer_status" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Customer Status')) ?>" class="select">
            <option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please Select Status.')) ?></option>
            <option value="a"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('A')) ?></option>
            <option value="b"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('B')) ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step :6** After run below commands

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: i will check that  :)

Comment: I tried your code but nothing shown in table none in form *

Comment: have you checked admin side under customer?

Comment: i will check that

Comment: yes nothing extra

Comment: attribute created or not. Please check attribute in database?

Comment: yes i checked in database nothing added

Comment: have you run all commands? or check admin side cache enabled or disable. if cache enabled then clear cache and check again

Comment: yes Abdull now i changed the UpgradeData to Install Data but no result

Comment: it's not adding in database

Comment: i  also cleared the cache but no result

Comment: have you run all commands ?

Comment: yes Abdull all the command

Comment: Pls check here xyz/app/etc/config.php your module there or not?

Comment: 'Stack_Customer' => 1, yes it's there

Comment: then module setup is fine. Once again check your database table "eav_attribute" attribute there or not

Comment: ok  iw ill do that

Comment: ok now i found this new attribute but whay not shownig in registerform

Comment: Ok good. now available admin side under customer right?

Comment: yes but how to make it shown in registration form

Comment: Now override vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml file in your theme and add    select type in this file for attribute

Comment: how to call this attribute in register.phtml

Comment: and is it necessary to override some layout ??

Comment: no need to override layout file

Comment: ok so how to call the new attribute please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84906/discussion-between-abdul-and-developper-magento).

Comment: Add in your register.phtml  file<div class="field customer_status"> 
<label for="customer_status" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer Status')) ?></span></label> 
<div class="control"> 
<select id="customer_status" name="customer_status" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Customer Status')) ?>" class="select"> 
<option value=""><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Please select.')) ?></option> 
<option value="a"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('A')) ?></option> 
<option value="b"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('B')) ?></option> 
</select> 
</div>

Comment: thanks a lot Abdul  and i am sorry for not replaying fast it was  our break time

Comment: i finally get the attribute in  registration form but why  am i having  A B in select options and not Active , On Hold Inactive ?

Comment: Yes, i have put static please do this dynamic :)

Comment: but in admin i can see active and Onhold

Comment: Also i want to have static value

Comment: why do i have the value of options duplicated and why do i have juste A B as options in registration form

Comment: please check my apdated question and really thanks a lot